# Application failed to start - org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter

Tags: java, spring, exception, logging, application.properties

I was using eclipse for Spring Boot Projects. All projects were working fine but don't know what happened, while running the applications I am getting below error. It is trying to find in Desktop Folder, instead of the resource folder. Instead previously created & working projects are also not working.
Even a project with single rest controller giving me the same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuYf2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lonpr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixQVo.png)

**Pom.xml**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.2
 

com.luv2code.springboot.demo
mycoolapp
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
mycoolapp
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- ADD SUPPORT FOR AUTOMATIC RELOADING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Console:**

00:25:43.687 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource 'file [C:\Users\kashi\Desktop\application.properties]' via location 'C:/Users/kashi/Desktop/application.properties' cannot be found
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.withLocation(ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.handle(ConfigDataImporter.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:115)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:242)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:229)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
at com.luv2code.springboot.demo.mycoolapp.MycoolappApplication.main(MycoolappApplication.java:10)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
00:25:43.707 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Config data resource 'file [C:\Users\kashi\Desktop\application.properties]' via location 'C:/Users/kashi/Desktop/application.properties' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'C:/Users/kashi/Desktop/application.properties' is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'

I have tried all the possible things which came into my mind like using a different workspace, removing dependencies from local maven repositories & reinstalling the eclipse. Now, I am now not able to run any Spring Boot project in my system, so please help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

Someone given me the answer to do either of the two ways:

1. Maven clean and maven install
2. Set optional properties in Application.properties file
   but nothing worked and this issue frustated me and I left using this system for a week.

Today, I again tried looking into this problem and somehow I thought of cheking path variable as this issue was not specific to project. So, I checked path variable and found that in System variables, "spring.config.location" is being set with Desktop location. I immediately deleted this variable and restarted the eclipse and it worked.

Hope this will help someone if they face the same issue.